# I wanna see the position that I'm scrolling on at recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have an activity and its related adapter.when I pass a list to my adapter,In onBindViewHolder I've put a Log and whenever I scroll my recyclerview,I can see the exact position that I'm scrolling on;and I have no problem with that.
But I have another class and its related adapter that these two adapter are similar.But in second recyclerview I can't see the position that I'm scrolling on; And Logcat show me all the position at a time.

I will show you both of myclasses and their related adapters:
First(Without problem):

```
public class adapteeer extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapteeer.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private MyActivity mContext;
public static ArrayList<Question> questionlist;

public adapteeer(MyActivity context, ArrayList<Question> objects) {

    mContext = context;
    questionlist = objects;
    ...
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.question_items_activity, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewHolder gridViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return gridViewHolder;
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ....

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
       ....
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Log.e("possssss", position + "");

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questionlist.size();
}
}
```

and Logcat for this adapter:

```
02-13 11:44:19.663 22463-22463/com.example.qa E/possssss: 0
02-13 11:44:19.738 22463-22463/com.example.qa E/possssss: 1
```

Because I can just see 2 rows of my recyclerview.

And the other adapter:(that gives me all the position at a time)

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterUnseenNoti extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterUnseenNoti.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Notification> notilist;

public RecyclerViewAdapterUnseenNoti(Context context, ArrayList<Notification> objects) {
    mContext = context;
    notilist = objects;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.notification_items_activity, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewHolder gridViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return gridViewHolder;
}


public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   ...

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

       ...
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Log.e("possssss", position + "");

    final Notification notification = notilist.get(position);
    ....
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notilist.size();
}
}
```

But for this adapter Logcat show me all the position at fisrt:(eventhough I can just see 3 items of list in my screen)

```
02-13 14:16:09.865 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 0
02-13 14:16:09.900 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 1
02-13 14:16:09.920 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 2
02-13 14:16:09.940 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 3
02-13 14:16:09.960 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 4
02-13 14:16:09.980 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 5
02-13 14:16:10.005 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 6
02-13 14:16:10.030 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 7
02-13 14:16:10.065 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 8
02-13 14:16:10.090 22316-22316/com.example.qa E/possssss: 9
```

And I don't know why!

Comment: it is really strange....If you found the reason must share

Comment: If your items contain a textview and you can set different texts for positions then you should be able to put the position in it too.

Comment: @greenapps I tried what you said.And I can see each position in its related row. and still  nothing has been changed!

Comment: @AbdulWaheed sure!

Comment: Sorry... If you can see the position in every item then what is it that you dont see?

Comment: @greenapps the problam is: I want to see the position if I am focused on that row! I mean if I can just see 3 rows of my recyclerview in my screen,so I have to see position 0,1,2 in logcat. and when I scoll for seeing another items,I have to see other position like 3,4,5.but my problam is I see all the positions at first(position 0,1,2,3,4,5,....) eventhough I can just see 2 items of recyclerview and I dont scroll on the other position.

Comment: @greenapps the main reason for doing this work is that I want to know when I reached the last item for showing progressbar and "Loading" word for getting more data.but with this problem at the first of starting activity,it shows me all the position and it means that I reached the end of the list.but it isn't so.

Comment: Dont understand. A minute ago you said you were able to put the position in every item. What does it matter that you scroll? The textview of every item will display its own text and the position.

Comment: @greenapps I dont have any problam for getting position.The only problam is getting them one by one.not all in one!

Comment: It is pretty confusing that you seem to talk about item positions which you wanna see in the listview but also in a log. I cannot follow you.

Comment: @greenapps I'm so sorry for confusing you! and thanks for taking some times for me.I think I have to think more about this story:D and also try more.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed the reason just was because of putting my recyclerview in a scrollview! By taking it out, the issue was solved!!!

Comment: @F.Mi aahhh I see.... great to see you have solved it. And thanks to update me :)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed you're welcom:)